# Is an alias template considered equal to the "same" template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-templates

**The context**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61278669/4117728) asked if it is possible to write a trait that can retrieve the template from a given instantiation. In a nutshell the question was: "Is it possible to write a `f` such that `f<foo<int>>::type` is `foo`?"

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61279178/4117728) presents something that I would have expected to be exactly what that question asked for, but the answer already mentions that it is "not exactly" what has been asked for.

**The code**

To see the code in action and understand why it was labeled as "not exactly" I wrote this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// the template
template <typename T> struct foo {};

// not the template
template <typename T> struct not_foo {};


template <template<class> class A, template<class> class B>
struct is_same_template : std::false_type {};

// this is the questionable part    
template <template<class> class A>
struct is_same_template<A,A> : std::true_type {};

// copied from said answer
template <typename T> struct template_class;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct template_class<C<T>> 
{
    template <typename U>
    using type = C<U>;
};

// what will we get?
int main (){
    std::cout << is_same_template<foo,foo>::value;
    std::cout << is_same_template<foo,not_foo>::value;
    std::cout << is_same_template<foo, template_class<foo<int>>::type>::value;
}
```

**The output**

What I was expecting, gcc:

```
101
```

My surprise, clang:

```
100
```

[@ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vbmyKX)

**The question**

Who is right here? Gcc, because `template_class< foo<int> >::type` is `foo`? Or clang, becaue comparing two different templates for equality doesn't make much sense?

If the outcome is implementation defined, or undefined, then what exactly in the code is undefined / implementation defined?

**PS**

At first I was expecting the outcome of gcc with no doubts, but in the meantime I was convinced that my expectations were not quite founded, hence this question.